# Deleting all regex instances starting with char '[' and ending with char ']' from a String

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, tostring

I need to take a `String` and deleting all the regexes in it starting with `character` '[' and ending with `character` ']'.

Now i don't know how to tackle this problem. I tried to convert the `String` to character array and then putting empty characters from any starting '[' till his closing ']' and then convert it back to a `String` using `toString()` method.

**MyCode:**

```
char[] lyricsArray = lyricsParagraphElements.get(1).text().toCharArray();
                for (int i = 0;i < lyricsArray.length;i++)
                {
                    if (lyricsArray[i] == '[')
                    {
                        lyricsArray[i] = ' ';
                        for (int j = i + 1;j < lyricsArray.length;j++)
                        {
                            if (lyricsArray[j] == ']')
                            {
                                lyricsArray[j] = ' ';
                                i = j + 1;
                                break;
                            }
                            lyricsArray[j] = ' ';
                        }   
                    }
                }
                String songLyrics = lyricsArray.toString();
                System.out.println(songLyrics);
```

But in the print line of songLyrics i get weird stuff like

```
[C@71bc1ae4
[C@6ed3ef1
[C@2437c6dc
[C@1f89ab83
[C@e73f9ac
[C@61064425
[C@7b1d7fff
[C@299a06ac
[C@383534aa
[C@6bc168e5
```

I guess there is a simple method for it. Any help will be very appreciated.

For clarification:
converting `"abcd[dsadsadsa]efg[adf%@1]d"` Into `"abcdefgd"`

Comment: Use `new String(lyricsArray)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner On what and where?

Comment: There is a [`String` constructor that takes a `char[]` as its argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char[]%29).

Comment: Instead of `lyricsArray.toString()`

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks you. I will try it.

Comment: You can also simply call `System.out.println(lyricsArray);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or simply use a regular expression to [replace all](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) occurences of `\\[.*\\]` with nothing:

```
String songLyrics = text.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "");
```

Where `text` is ofcourse:

```
String text = lyricsParagraphElements.get(1).text();
```

---

**What does `\\[.*\\]` mean?**

The first parameter of `replaceAll` is a string describing a regular expression. A regular expression defines a pattern to match in a string.

So let's split it up:

`\\[` matches exactly the character `[`. Since `[` has a [special meaning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) within a regular expression, it needs to be escaped (twice!).

`.` matches any character, combine this with the ([lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)) zero-or-more operator `*?`, and it will match any character until it finally finds:

`\\]`, which matches the character `]`. Note the escaping again.

Comment: Can you explain what the first parameter `\\[.\\]` mean?

Comment: Given the example input/output, you should use the ? quantifier on `.*`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Please explain.

Comment: @Tim greedy matching changes `abcd[dsadsadsa]efg[adf%@1]d` to `abcdd`, not the desired output.

Comment: That's more accurate but still not perfect. fortunately I don't need it to be perfect. It's not perfect because taking `"[Chorus 2x - Eminem:]` making it `"2x"` but as i said it's ok for me. Thanks.

Comment: @God It shouldn't. I think there is another error in you code.

Comment: @God If I execute `System.out.println("a[Chorus 2x - Eminem:]b".replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", ""));` it will print `ab`. So this should work for you. Can you maybe post your code on [ideone](https://ideone.com/)?

Comment: @Tim It's fine. My code is too big and complicated. But i got what i wanted and that's what matters. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your code below is referencing to the string object and you are then printing the reference `songLyrics`.

```
String songLyrics = lyricsArray.toString();
System.out.println(songLyrics);
```

Replace above two lines with

```
String songLyrics = new String(lyricsArray);
System.out.println(songLyrics);
```

[Ideone1](http://ideone.com/QURRXr)

Other way without converting it into char array and again to string.

```
String lyricsParagraphElements = "asdasd[asd]";

String songLyrics = lyricsParagraphElements.replaceAll("\\[.*\\]", "");

System.out.println(songLyrics);
```

[Ideone2](http://ideone.com/QURRXr)

Comment: Yes. That's good. But It's really necessary to convert the `String` into characters array and then delete and then converting back. There is no method in `java` that can do it in one line? like someone suggested ` lyricsParagraphElements.get(1).text().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", " ")`??

Comment: @FallAndLearn Little unnecessary to clone my answer. It isn't even correct: `lyricsParagraphElements` isn't of type `String`.

Comment: @Tim Hi. I didn't copied your answer. In fact I was the first one to post and then he asked about the other way. replaceAll() method is the most simple and concise solution to above problem.

Comment: @FallAndLearn Which you edited in 4 minutes after mine. Anyway, it isn't correct.

Comment: See the first comment on my answer. He asked another way to come to the required solution.

Comment: I just took an example string variable name as lyricsParagraphElements. It can be anything.

Comment: Which is posted after mine. However the answer is still wrong, I guess that `lyricsParagraphElements` is an `Collection`. Besides your regex will match anything between `[` and `]` greedy, which means that every thing between the first `[` and the last `]` will be removed. Consider a string with multiple occurrences: `123[a]4[b]5[c]67[d]8[e]9` will become `1239` instead of `123456789`. I made the same mistake though. Andy Turner noted the error.

Comment: @Tim You are right tim. The `replaceAll("\\[.*\\]", "");` not working.

Comment: I checked it. Above will only replace the characters inside first []. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting "weird stuff" because you are printing the string representation of the array, not converting the array to a String.

Instead of `lyricsArray.toString()`, use

```
new String(lyricsArray);
```

But if you do this, you will find that you are not actually removing characters from the string, just replacing them with spaces.

Instead, you can shift all of the characters left in the array, and construct the new String only up to the right number of characters:

```
int src = 0, dst = 0;
while (src < lyricsArray.length) {
  while (src < lyricsArray.length && lyricsArray[src] != '[') {
    lyricsArray[dst++] = lyricsArray[src++];
  }
  if (src < lyricsArray.length) {
    ++src;
    while (src - 1 < lyricsArray.length && lyricsArray[src - 1] != ']') {
      src++;
    }
  }
}
String lyricsString = new String(lyricsArray, 0, dst);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're printing a `char[]` and Java `char[]` does not override `toString()`. And, a Java `String` is *immutable*, but Java does have [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which is *mutable* (and [`StringBuilder.delete(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete-int-int-) can remove arbitrary substrings). You could use it like,

```
String songLyrics = lyricsParagraphElements.get(1).text();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(songLyrics);
int p = 0;
while ((p = sb.indexOf("[", p)) >= 0) {
    int e = sb.indexOf("]", p + 1);
    if (e > p) {
        sb.delete(p, e + 1);
    }
    p++;
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly regex string for your case:

```
\\[([\\w\\%\\@]+)\\]
```

It's very hard when your plant string is contain special symbol. I can't find shorter regex, without explain special symbol like an exception.
reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg

================

I'm read your new case, a string contain symbol "-" or something else in
    !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~
add them (with prefix "\\") after \\@ on my regex string.

Comment: So changing `String songLyrics = text.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "");` to `String songLyrics = text.replaceAll("\[([\w\%\@]+)\]", "");`? will make it perfect? because `Eclipse` saying it's invalid escape sequence.

Comment: @God: I don't know why, when \\ (two backslash) is replate to \ (one backslash). I'm corrected it. Please remember it's always \\, not \.

Comment: @God: I mind stackoverflow is confusing me by auto replace 2 backslash to 1 backslash. Try string i'm quote in code tag and enjoy.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205033/mystring-replaceallregex-not-working-as-expected. Thank you.